# Android orientation lock according to screen size

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I have created one app with a splash screen. In the onCreate i check the device screen size and i set splash screen orientation, protrait for <5" and landscape for larger screens. After that, according to the screen size i start the HomeScreenNormal or HomeScreenTablet Activities which have different layouts. I have two questions:

1. Is it better to check for screens larger than 5" using

```
if((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & 
 Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE){
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

or using

```
private float getDeviceWidthInDP(){
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
    display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

    float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float dpWidth  = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;

    return dpWidth;
}
```

to find the device widthInDp and after that, check if

```
if(device_dpWidth > 480){
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeScreenTablet.class);
        startActivity(intent);

}
```

*the above code is from stackoverflow*.

1. I can't lock the whole app in either potrait or landscape mode. I want acivities for devices larger than 5" to be in landscape and for devices smaller than 5" to be in portrait. Which is the best way to achieve this?

   1. Declaring in the manifest the appropriate activities with [screenorientation](/questions/tagged/screenorientation)?
      or
   2. Using the [setrequestorientation](/questions/tagged/setrequestorientation) inside the onCreate of each activity?